# How to assign some value to a specific index of an array in jstl?

Tags: arrays, string, jsp, split, jstl

I have a variable `imageUrl` which I'm splitting wrt `.` and storing in an array `imageUrlParts` as follows:

```
<c:set var="imageUrlParts" value="${fn:split(imageUrl, '.')}" />
```

Now, I just want to append something more to the second last token of that. For instance if the URL is `a.b.c.d` then I want to make it `a.b.cSOMETHINGADDED.d`. So I am doing the following:

```
<c:set var="len" value="${fn:length(imageUrlParts)}" />
<c:set var="imageUrlParts[len-2]" value="${imageUrlParts[len-2]}SOMETHINGADDED" />
<c:set var="imageUrl" value="${fn:join(imageUrlParts, '.')}" />
```

But it is not working, as in, it is reconstructing it as `a.b.c.d` itself and **NOT** `a.b.cSOMETHINGADDED.d`, which means that the following line

```
<c:set var="imageUrlParts[len-2]" value="${imageUrlParts[len-2]}SOMETHINGADDED" />
```

is not working (of course). Can you tell me how I should achieve what I want to do?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is demonstration code. If you don't want to use the first line, then you will have to put the forEach tag code on one line. That would avoid spaces within output String.

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="imageUrl" value="a.b.c.d" />
<c:set var="imageUrlParts" value="${fn:split(imageUrl, '.')}" />
<c:set var="len" value="${fn:length(imageUrlParts)}" />
<c:forEach var="part" items="${imageUrlParts}" varStatus="status">
    ${part}
<c:if test="${(len -1) == status.count}">SOMETHINGADDED</c:if>
<c:if test="${!status.last}">.</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```